# Show that if $B$ is the inverse matrix of $A^2$, then $AB$ is the inverse matrix of $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, inverse

Let $A, B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be invertible matrices. Show: If $B$ is the inverse matrix of $A^2$, then $AB$ is the inverse matrix of $A$

---

$AA \cdot (B) = I$ then $A \cdot (AB) = I$ so obviously $AB$ is the inverse of $A$

---

Is this really that simple ?

Comment: Yes, it is indeed that simple. Well done!

Comment: It depends if $A^2$ is an element wise multiplication.

Comment: You also need $(AB)A=I$

Comment: @Andrei Yes but multiplying the inverse left or right gives the same result, isn't it ?

Comment: You just proved half, that it's a right inverse. You need to show that it's a left inverse as well, or the equivalent, that it is invertible (or that the determinant is not 0)

Comment: Since $A$ is invertible, just take your last equation, multiply on the left with $A^{-1}$ and on the right with $A$. You will get $(A^{-1}A)(AB)A=A^{-1}A$, or $(AB)A=I$. This is true **only** if $A$ is invertible.